# How to rotate an object on the local axis?

Tags: animation

I am adding a Torus and **after rotating it a little bit on the Z** i have to rotate it on the X, but its being rotated wrongly as you see.
I want my torus to be rotated straight like a tire.
I have asked this question before but my previous question and the answer was very complicated, i did not understand anything so this time i want to make it simpler if its possible. Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Hitting <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will rotate an object about its local Z axis.

The second time you hit <kbd>Z</kbd> switches from global to local axes.

---

If you want to default to local axes, you can switch the mode from "Global" to "Local" in the header of the 3D view:

[image: Switching from global to local rotation]

---

About your specific case:

In Blender, a torus is created with its **local** Z axis pointing through the hole at its center. Unless you have applied its rotations since it was created, hitting <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will rotate it about its local Z axis. (You'll see  the axis displayed as a blue line). The second time you hit <kbd>Z</kbd>, in this case, switches from global to local axes.

Or, if you turn on your rotation gizmo (the small button with an arc on it to the left of where it says Global' in the header at the bottom of your 3D view), and switch the 'Global' to 'Local', you'll see the axes available to you.

Comment: I just read [elsewhere](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-modify-an-objects-local-coordinate-system/424830) that Alt-space changes the mode from "global" to "local", then "normal", then "view", then back to "global". I'll test it.

Comment: HI @user2987828.. could be.. on my machine it's covered by an OS shortcut. so better for you to check. Personally, I use ',' (comma) and a pie menu to switch.