# How do i rotate this object properly?

Tags: axis

[image]

Apologies if this is a fairly common question. I want to rotate the wheel that is selected in the picture like how a regular wheel rotates. How do I adjust the gimble so that it lines up with the orientation of the wheel? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105398/how-to-rotate-an-object-on-the-local-axis if if doesn't answer your question then, please, come back and edit your question to clarify the details of the problem.

Comment: There are also lots of YT videos on rigging wheel animation, for instance [this](https://youtu.be/V2shn1LpcNE) one by Pixxo 3D. It's for Blender 2.83 but is the same in version 3